# Add inline style to element in XML Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, xml, styles

How do I apply an inline style to an element in an XML layout file in Magento 2?

```
<container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="header" before="main.content"/>
```

I am looking to add inline styles to the header element above, but I cannot find any reference on how to do this, I tried htmlStyle and this does not appear to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my research, you can't set inline style on a `container` element.

**The Arguments**

- In the classes responsible for interpreting this type of xml element, `Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Container` and `Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Container`, you'll find the names of `container` options in layout, which are used for performing validations:

  `const CONTAINER_OPT_HTML_TAG = 'htmlTag';
  const CONTAINER_OPT_HTML_CLASS = 'htmlClass';
  const CONTAINER_OPT_HTML_ID = 'htmlId';
  const CONTAINER_OPT_LABEL = 'label';`
- Also, when the xml's are converted into html output, in `Magento\Framework\View\Layout`, you'll find in `_renderContainer($name)` method, this line `$html = sprintf('<%1$s%2$s%3$s>%4$s</%1$s>', $htmlTag, $htmlId, $htmlClass, $html);`, which means that only tags, ids and classes are included in the html output.

The arguments are strengthened by magento documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_cont, which presents the allowed options for a `container` element, without specifying any inline customisations.

The only option I can see is to use `htmlClass`. If there's a way to do that and I'm wrong, please leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Alex's answer above, you will need to use CSS/LESS for styling as you can't directly do it inline in XML.

1. Create a stylesheet for your module.

   - `Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\css\source\_module.less`
2. Add your CSS/LESS styling to that sheet
3. If in `developer` mode:

   - Clear the `pub/static` cached files with: `rm -rf pub/static/`
   - Clear the `var/view_preprocessed` cached files with: `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed`
4. If in `production` mode:

   - Deploy static content: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
5. If caches are enabled

   - Clear the cache: `php bin/magento cache:clean`
6. Refresh the page

NOTE: I've seen some other sources suggest that you need to run an upgrade.  I didn't need to in `developer` mode but wanted to mention it in case others find it necessary.  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Also worth mentioning that you can use an ID as well as an HTML Class.  In your XML you can set these to the `container` with the following syntax:

**Set ID:**

```
<container name="custom.container" as="custom_container" htmlTag="div" label="Custom Container" htmlId="custom_css_id" />
```

**Set Class:**

```
<container name="custom.container" as="custom_container" htmlTag="div" label="Custom Container" htmlClass="custom_css_class" />
```

**Set ID and Class:**

```
<container name="custom.container" as="custom_container" htmlTag="div" label="Custom Container" htmlId="custom_css_id" htmlClass="custom_css_class" />
```